# EF 7 beta 5 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

How do I get beta 5 for EF in VS 2015 RC?? Beta 5 was released 17 days ago but I still cant use it??

I tried Install-Package EntityFramework.Core-Pre and it now thinks beta 5 is the version in the NuGet manager but when I type:

PM> dnu restore

I get:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta5-12103

Restoring packages for C:\Users\tuppe\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AngularProject\src\AngularProject\project.json
 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/entityframework/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.runtime/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Runtime'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Runtime/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.text.encoding/index.json
 GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Text.Encoding'
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.globalization/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Globalization/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.runtime.interopservices/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Runtime.InteropServices'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Runtime.InteropServices/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.threading.tasks/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Threading.Tasks'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Threading.Tasks/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.io/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.IO'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.IO/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.reflection/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Reflection/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.collections/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Collections'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Collections/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.runtime.extensions/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Runtime.Extensions'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Runtime.Extensions/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.linq.expressions/index.json
 GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Linq.Expressions'
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.threading/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Threading'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Threading/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.diagnostics.debug/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Diagnostics.Debug'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Diagnostics.Debug/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.collections.concurrent/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Collections.Concurrent'
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Collections.Concurrent/4.0.0-beta-23019
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.threading.threadpool/index.json
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Threading.ThreadPool'
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/entityframework/index.json 683ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.globalization/index.json 496ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.threading.tasks/index.json 493ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.reflection/index.json 487ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.text.encoding/index.json 517ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.io/index.json 493ms
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.text.encoding/4.0.0-beta-23019/system.text.encoding.4.0.0-beta-23019.nupkg
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.linq.expressions/index.json 487ms
 GET https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.linq.expressions/4.0.0-beta-23019/system.linq.expressions.4.0.0-beta-23019.nupkg
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.runtime/index.json 584ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.collections/index.json 539ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.collections.concurrent/index.json 498ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.threading/index.json 539ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.runtime.interopservices/index.json 577ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.runtime.extensions/index.json 578ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.threading.threadpool/index.json 508ms
 CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Threading.ThreadPool/4.0.10-beta-22231
 OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Linq.Expressions' 607ms
 OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Text.Encoding' 678ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.diagnostics.debug/index.json 841ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.text.encoding/4.0.0-beta-23019/system.text.encoding.4.0.0-beta-23019.nupkg 439ms
 OK https://nugetapiapps.blob.core.windows.net/ngx/system.linq.expressions/4.0.0-beta-23019/system.linq.expressions.4.0.0-beta-23019.nupkg 450ms
 dnu : Unable to locate EntityFramework >= 7.0.0-beta5
 At line:1 char:1
•dnu restore
•~~~~~~~~~~~ ◦CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (Unable to locat... >= 7.0.0-beta5:String) [], RemoteException
◦FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Writing lock file C:\Users\tuppe\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AngularProject\src\AngularProject\project.lock.json
 Restore complete, 2791ms elapsed
 Errors in C:\Users\tuppe\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AngularProject\src\AngularProject\project.json
Unable to locate 


EntityFramework


= 7.0.0-beta5
```

It appear the beta 5 is not on NuGet yet but it has been released so how do I get it?

Comment: Your error refers to EntityFramework, not EntityFramework.Core. Maybe you have an old reference in your project.json? The thing is, when you install a package with a new name (such as EF.Core), it won't know to uninstall the package with the old name (EntityFramework), so you'll have references to both.